# TPL Dataflow blocks run forever. Forever running producer, consumer modelling and exception handling

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am using TPL Dataflow library to implement a producer consumer scenario. The processing involves a pipeline of tasks. Dataflow library aptly suits my use case.

But I want to know how do I efficiently implement this use case [details below].

I want to use TPL Dataflow in a server type setting.

By a server type setting I mean production of data stream takes place continuously [asynchronously] forever. Consumption task also runs forever and consumes all the data produced by a producer[asynchronusly].
**Thus my blocks run forever**

How do I model this scenario efficiently? Moreover how can I deal with exception  handling as I cannot `Wait()` [Without a call to `Wait()` I would not be able to catch the exceptions thrown on a faulted block as far as my understanding goes].

Comment: Consider Reactive Extensions (Rx) instead. TPL Dataflow behavior is that, once a network of blocks has faulted, it stays faulted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Exceptions

I usually wrap the delegates with exception handling because as you said a block's exception is stored in the `Completion` task and moreover a faulted block stays faulted so you would need to replace it to move on.

```
var block = new TransfromBlock<string, int>(number =>
{
    try
    {
        return int.Parse(number);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(e);
    }
});
```

### Capacity

Another important issue is capping. If some part of your workflow can't handle the load, it's input queue would simply grow infinitely. That could lead to a memory leak or `OutOfMemoryException`s. So it's important to make sure to limit all your blocks with the appropriate `BoundedCapacity` and decide what to do when that limit is reached ("throw" items, save to storage, etc.)

### Parallelism

While the default value for `BoundedCapacity` is -1 (unbounded), the default value for `MaxDegreeOfPrallelism` is 1 (no parallelism). Most applications can easily benefit from parallelism so make sure to set an appropriate `MaxDegreeOfPrallelism` value. When a block's delegate is purely CPU-intensive `MaxDegreeOfPrallelism` shouldn't be much higher than the available cores. As it has less CPU and more I/O-intensive parts the `MaxDegreeOfPrallelism` can be increased.

### Conclusion

Using TPL dataflow throughout the application's lifetime is really simple. Just make sure to enable configuration through the `app.config` and tweak according to actual results "in the field".